# Django include template tag include multiple context object

Tags: python, django

I`m building a blog template page, which will include the Post list context object and the Category list context object.

I`m using class-based view in the views.py:

```
class CatListView(ListView):
model = Category
context_object_name = 'categories'
template_name = 'blog/category.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post_list' 
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='blog'),
...
]
```

using the include tag to include the category template in blog.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}

<main class="main-content">
    <div class="container mt-8">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h2>Post list</h2>
                {% for post in post_list %}

                {{ post.title }}

                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {% include "blog/category.html"%}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

category.html:

```
<ul class="mt-8">
    {% for cat in categories %}
    <li>{{ cat.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I just can`t pass the category context in the post.html template. maybe I`m can do it with the function-based view, but is it possible to pass multiple contexts into one template using only a class-based view?

Comment: Where is `post.html` i think you have a typo

Comment: @Ahtisham I put it in the third  box of code

Answer (score 1):

To return more than one context variables you can always override
[get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) method like this:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
  # rest of the code
  queryset = Post.objects.all()

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['extra_variable'] = # get extra context
      return context
```

Comment: Sorry, sir, I`m not able to get it, can you be more specific.

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: PostListView is missing a QuerySet.

Comment: From where are you importing `ListView` ?

Comment: from django.views.generic import ListView

Comment: I have added a link to `get_context_data` in my answer check it should work. Which line causes the exception can you mention here ?